# Конфигурационный файл и горячие клавиши в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, config

Нужно реализовать свои горячие клавиши для элементов меню. Например CTRL+S.

```
InputGestureCollection save = new InputGestureCollection();
save.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.S, ModifierKeys.Control));
```

Но настройки горячих клавиш должны храниться в файле конфигурации. Как записать эти настройки, и как потом прочитать их?

Comment: А как выглядит ваш файл конфигурации?

Comment: В том то и дело, что никак. Я не знаю, как правильно его записать, чтобы потом его прочитать. Поэтому и обратился сюда.

Comment: Окей, то есть не «хранятся в файле конфигурации», а «должны храниться», верно?

Comment: Да, неправильно сформулировал вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для сериализации WPF-объектов может пригодиться [`XamlReader`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xamlreader?view=netframework-4.7.1)/[`XamlWriter`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xamlwriter?view=netframework-4.7.1).

Получится такой код:

Сохранение:

```
InputGestureCollection coll = ...;
using (var config = File.Create(path))
    XamlWriter.Save(coll, config);
```

Восстановление:

```
InputGestureCollection coll;
using (var config = File.OpenRead(path))
    coll = (InputGestureCollection)XamlReader.Load(config);
```

Comment: И опять же вы меня неправильно поняли. Даже скорее я не могу нормально сформулировать вопрос. Настройки должны хранится в App.config

Comment: @tmoha: А как вы собираетесь писать в app.config? Он находится обычно в Program Files, в недоступном для записи каталоге.

Comment: Как я понял, при запуске программы читается этот файл, генерируется Имя_исполняемого_файла.exe.config. И из этого файла берутся настройки. Поправьте, если не так.

Comment: То есть это можно, наверное ([вот](http://yizeng.me/2013/08/31/update-appsettings-and-custom-configuration-sections-in-appconfig-at-runtime/)), но это вряд ли то место, где рекомендуется держать данные.

Comment: @tmoha: Да, но каталог с программой у юзера лежит в защищённом от записи каталоге Program Files.

Comment: Я вас понял. Следует написать свой файл конфигурации, и работать уже с ним.

Comment: @tmoha: ... и хранить его, например, в `%APPDATA%\название_вашей_программы\keys.xaml`.